# Cannot log out of phpMyAdmin v4.6.3

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, logout

I have phpMyAdmin v4.2.2 installed on my localhost WAMP (manual install) at `C:\Program Files\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin`. 
I just put phpMyAdmin v4.6.3 in at `C:\Program Files\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin 4_6_3` to test it before deleting v4.2.2, which still works well.

I set up the phpMyAdmin v4.6.3 config.inc.php with:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

I cannot logout. The "green left-pointing arrow logout button" says "Empty session data". All five of the other buttons behave normally.
When I Changed 'config' to 'cookie' I did get the login dialog, but it keeps reappearing. Changing back to 'config' restores the logged-in Home page.

Changing

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

did not help.

The URL "http://localhost/phpMyAdmin%204_6_3/phpmyadmin/index.php?old_usr=xy" (and other variants) did nothing. I got a page full of text, if anything.

WAMP is: Windows Home Premium 64 bit, Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17

Comment: First of all: localhost and 127.0.0.1 is an URL/IP that alwais points to the computer, that is looking that URL/IP up. So posting that link will do me no good, since it's trying to get the page from my computer, when I click on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost
Secondly: You could accept and not delete cookies on your browser and change the setting again to "cookie".

Comment: doh-nutz: I only posted the localhost link above to show that I did try that. I did not think to delete the localhost and 127.0.0.1 cookies, but I doubt if that will help. Further testing revealed that I can log into the Simple Machines Forum and Coppermine Photo Gallery installation on my localhost without any problems. Something in the MySQL server database for phpMyAdmin must be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after days of pouring over my Apache httpd.conf and PHP php.ini files. (I thought I might have changed something inadvertantly.)

I originally had phpMyAdmin v4.2.2 installed on my localhost WAMP (manual install) at
"C:\Program Files\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin" and the updated version at
"C:\Program Files\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin 4_6_3" until I was sure the new version worked.

I had a heck of a time wondering why v4.2.2 worked, but v4.6.3 did not. I found the answer at:
https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3893/

The directory and the URL (in my "index.htm") for v4.6.3 had "white-space" { %20 }, which was throwing off the token match. Now that I know that v4.6.3 is working, I deleted the v4.2.2 directory, renamed the v4.6.3 directory to the default, and deleted the v4.6.3 URL from my "index.htm". I also changed the 'auth_type' for v4.6.3 back to 'cookie'.